# Error message with implementing firebase on Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

So I was trying to implement Firebase on Android Studio, and this error message kept popping up

> "Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.1."

I know it says to update it. But how do I do that exactly?

Here is my build.gradle for the project

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jbdelosreyes.finalmvp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and here is my build.gradle for the module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jbdelosreyes.finalmvp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post `build.gradle` files here (both project level and app level gradle files)

Comment: Please post your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Hi! sorry im new to this. i've edited it now

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android SDK and update
- Google Play Service
- Google Repository

Comment: but there's no update available. so i'm assuming it's already up to date

Comment: If you compile or implement your module, in build.gradle (app) you do not need to call
     implementation 'com.google.firebase: firebase-core: 16.0.1'
     implementation 'com.google.firebase: firebase-firestore: 17.0.4'

or Show me your build.gradle (project)

Comment: i dont quite get it. but my build.gradle is included in the question now. i edited it earlier

Comment: Did you check and try the duplicate? it's the same question @AnotherJuan

Comment: duplicate? where do i see these duplicates? or do i go type this question in the search bar?

Comment: omg there really was an answer already. thanks man! so should i take down this post now?